# Error in Repeated digital sum in C

Tags: c

Digital sum of 65536 is 7, because 6+5+5+3+6=25 and  2+5 = 7
I just want to make the program for above task. But i didn't get correct answer when the first addition above 10

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N, sum = 0, temp;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    while(1)
    {
        temp = N%10;
        sum += temp;
        N = N/10;

        if(N==0) {
            if(sum>=10) {
                N = sum;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a c# question. Why did you tag it with 3 different languages?

Comment: It will be easier if you treat them as `char`s.

Comment: After assigning N = sum then make sum = 0

Comment: @saravana Rpeated digital sum is called the [digital root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root).

Comment: ***Use a debugger***!  Set a breakpoint, step through your program, and watch the values of `N`, `temp` and `sum`.  Then the problem is OBVIOUS!!

Comment: @abelenky Or you can just look at the program and think about the logic and it's obvious. Or one can mentally execute the program for, say, N = 55 and it's obvious. BTW, this could be written in a functional language in one line and it would be virtually impossible to make this mistake.

Comment: How would you want negative numbers to be handled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the digital sum directly by doing, if number is non-zero then

```
value=number % 9
```

if the value is 0 then consider sum of the digit is equal to 9.
read this [link](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum00.htm) to get idea about how it works

Comment: What's the theory behind this?

Comment: @herohuyongtao The digital root is indeed the value modulo 9, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Comment: @herohuyongtao It follows from the fact that 10 % 9 == 1 so (10**n) % 9 == 1 for all n. Thus abcd = (1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d) % 9 == (a+b+c+d) % 9

Answer (score 2):

In your example, using 65536, `sum` ends up being 25,  so you properly set `N = 25`, in an attempt to reduce the number further.

***However*** `sum` is STILL 25.... so you end up with `25 + 2 + 5 = 32` on the second try through the loop.
Then sum is still >= 10.
You set N = 32, and go through the loop again, this time sum gets 32 + 3 + 2... and it never ends.

When you set N to your initial sum, you also need to reset sum to zero.

```
if(N==0) {
    if(sum>=10) {
        N = sum;  // Set N = 25, to calculate 2 + 5
        sum = 0;  // Reset Sum to zero, so you don't end up with 25 + 2 + 5!!
    }
```